# Weather patterns on a world with a homogenous distribution of land and ocean?

Tags: planets, weather, water

What would the weather patterns be like on an Earth with a more homogenous distribution of land and ocean? That is, keep the overall amount of water the same, the ratio of water to land the same (about 3:1), but spread it all out more equally.

Comment: Do you have a map of the world? Knowing how the land and water are distributed would help.

Comment: Hello Drewch, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Your Q would have benefited from our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/40609). It's far too vague and expects far too much for our Stack. (Read the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). We try to avoid closing new user questions, but climate is *insanely complex.* It's not just the distribution of land... it's mountains and deserts and forests and the topography of land *underwater*... We need more than just the map @Anubia-Bastet asked for. We need a lot of details. Can you provide them?

Comment: It reads like you are essentially talking about splitting the world into boxes of say 1km x 1km x200km, then hitting the shuffle button, then asking what will be the weather. Which is very open ended, beyond answering with "chaotic and messy".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Honestly, "too complicated to answer with that lack of detail" is a useful answer in itself. I'll look into the sandbox, as recommended, and try to definitize things a bit more.